# Remove folder from C:\Users

Tags: windows-10

In my C:\Users, I have a folder '8NRWXRV4YI'. I've tried rmdir /q /s in command prompt, but I get the following:

[image]

I'm the only user logged in right now. I've no idea where this folder even came from. Am I unable to delete it?

Comment: What process is locking the files.  ProcessExplorer might help

Comment: Can you see who owns the folder contents?  See if there is a dodgy users associated with the folder.  They may be logged in or running a service and so preventing the folder from being deleted.

Comment: I've searched all the processes and didn't see those files listed. Owner seems to be SYSTEM, but I've changed it to my own user. Still can't delete it. Also, the User/8NRWXRV4YI folder appears to be empty. I have hidden files turned on and everything. Still blank.

Comment: I use this software called "Lock Hunter". You can search it online. I've had trouble deleting files with Zero bytes in the past. You can try to close running processes in the Task Manager too. Another cmd is del which works good for tricky files. You can use abbreviations to like this: del 8NR* for example for filenames that are too long.